# MPI_Isend/MPI_Recv in a multi-thread program

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmpi

I have a **MPI_Isend/MPI_Recv problem** in  a **multi-thread** program.

In the program:

**The first machine** has one thread does some computation and call `MPI_Isend` to send buffer to the second machine, and another thread is always trying to `MPI_Recv` data from the second machine. And the first thread will `MPI_Wait` its last `MPI_Isend` to complete before call `MPI_Isend` again.

**The second machine** does the exact same thing.

Then I got the result that :

**The first machine**:

Thread **0**: `MPI_Isend` data to the second machine successfully. but blocked in `MPI_Wait` because last `MPI_Isend` did not complete.

Thread **1**: try to `MPI_Recv` data from the second machine, but no data and it blocked.

**The second machine**:

Thread **0**: `MPI_Isend` data to the first machine successfully. but blocked in `MPI_Wait` because last `MPI_Isend` did not complete.

Thread **1**: try to `MPI_Recv` data from the first machine, but no data and it blocked.

Does anyone have any ideas?   I appreciated it very much, because I have tracked the problem for two days but no progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to execute MPI calls concurrently, you have to initialise the MPI library with support for threads at level `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`. To do so you have to replace the call to `MPI_Init` with:

```
int provided;

MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
if (provided != MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE)
{
    printf("Sorry, this MPI implementation does not support multiple threads\n");
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
}
```

Some MPI libraries have to be compiled in a certain (non-default) way in order to support calls from multiple threads. For example, Open MPI has to be configured at library build time. Other vendors provide two versions of their libraries - one with support for threads and one without and you have to chose the correct one when you link your code. This is because adding support for threads increases the latency of many MPI calls and no one wants that if his program does not use threads.

Comment: @user1809434, and what do you get back in the `provided` argument? Does the MPI library return `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` or not?

Comment: MPI library supports MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE.

Comment: @user1809434, care to show some code? It's very hard to guess why something gives an error without the proper context.

Comment: Sorry that I have given some misleading hint.

Comment: @user1809434, you should accept the answer then so that other people could know that it solves your problem even without reading all the comments.